# Handling long running tasks with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to migrate an `AsyncTask` that sends messages to the server, to use RxJava. Roughly, the task does the following:

1) Creates a message that will be sent (persists to the database)
2) Shows the message to the user (state 'sending')
3) Sends the message to the server (code snippet below)
4) Marks the message as sent or failed (persists to the database)
5) Updates the UI

I've created the required Rx chain which partially looks like this:

```
 public Observable<Message> sendMessage(Message message) {
     return mApiClient.sendMessage(message)
         .doOnNext(sentMessage -> mDatabase.synchroniseMessage(sentMessage))
         .doOnError(e -> {
             message.setState(FAILED);
             mDatabase.synchroniseMessage(message));
         })
         .onErrorReturn(e -> Observable.just(message));
```

When I subscribe to the above, I get a `Disposable`. Normally I'd add it to the `CompositeDisposable` object and `clear` that object then the user has moved to a different `view` (i.e. `fragment`). However, in this case, I need to keep running this task to make sure the local database is updated with the task results accordingly.

What would be the most appropriate way to handle this situation? I could simply not add the `Disposable` into my `CompositeDisposable` object and therefore it wouldn't be unsubscribed from, but it feels like it could cause issues.

P.S. Showing updates to the user is handled through observing the data in an SQLite table. These events are triggered by the `synchroniseMessage` method. This is a different subscription which I will simply unsubscribe from, so it's not part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One disposes of `Disposable` as soon as he is no longer interested in it.

In your case you are still interested in the stream regardless user navigates to another screen or no, which means you cannot unsubscribe from it. Which means you cannot add it to `CompositeDisposable`.

This will result in a situation, when your `Activity` cannot be garbage collected, because of a implicit reference to it from your `Subscription`, hence you are creating a memory leak situation.

If you have such a use case, I think you have to perform that request on a component, which will be activity lifecycle independent, like [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: I would really like to avoid using `Service` or going back to using an `AsyncTask`. That would both have an impact on my architecture as well as reduce my options for unit testing the logic. I'm trying to understand how unsafe it is to just not keep a reference to a `Disposable`, cause it will terminate eventually (15 seconds `OkHttp` timeout period) and dispose of the subscription... Or I could store that subscription somewhere accessible and have a polling task to cull disposables every so often...

Comment: The only problem I see, is that you'd block GC to reclaim the memory that your `Activity` owns just for 15 second. After that, the next GC event will normally clean up activity. So, basically, you are behaving like a bad boy for only 15 seconds.

Comment: But if user keeps rotation device multiple times sequentially and you subscribe again each time - `OutOfMemoryException` will happen.

Comment: Well, rotating device does not automatically establish the `sendMessage` subscription. `sendMessage` is a user initiated action, when the user literally presses the send message button after typing in the message. But I see your point in theory.